# Manipulate Array with foreach loop and a callback

Tags: arrays, node.js, foreach, callback

I was manipulating an array with a for loop. How can I do this with a forEach loop and a function? I tried this, but I'm getting an undefined in the output.

```
var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'rat'];

pets = pets.forEach( function plural(value, index, array){
    value = value + 's';
    return value;
})


/*for ( i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
    pets[i] = pets[i] + 's';
}
*/

console.log(pets);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pets.forEach( function plural(value, index){
    pets[index]  = value + 's';
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pets = pets.map( function plural(value, index, array){
    return value + 's';
})
```